# Unlock GPO enabled "Lock all taskbars" on one PC

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, windows-server-2016

I am facing strange problem here. We have GPO that disables "Lock all taskbar" function in Windows 10. One user somehow managed to resize the taskbar and I want to fix this but its giving me a headache because I don't want to disable this policy for all domain users so I was thinking if there is an option to disable this policy as local gpo. Looks like it's not working so I tried a lot different methods - searching for a register to disable this policy didn't work as well because I just cannot edit the registry found in here:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer` called `LockTheTaskbar`and it returns me an error `*Error writing the value's new contents*`
I am feeling a bit desperate about this problem what seems not a really like a big problem.

I tried easy way of course just to place this PC in OU where this policy excludes. Did a force gpupdate, multiple times restarted machine and no updates. I can confirm that this machine is in our network

Answer (score 2):

This is a user setting, not a computer setting. You can't exclude it by moving the computer account to another OU as this setting isn't applied to the computer, it's applied to the user.

Create an OU for the user account and move the user account there. Create a GPO that sets the "Lock all taskbar settings" setting to disabled or not configured. Move the user account to this OU. Run gpupdate/force as the user or have the user either reboot their computer or log out and back in. Fix the taskbar. Move the user account back to it's original OU.

Comment: Aren't there extra settings for the taskbar position and size? I mean, if you use GPO to stop users from changing the settings, there is no harm in specifying what the setting should be.

Comment: There are, but this isn't my question. I'm just answering the OP's question as posted.